# Delete html files from path

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create a classified site from scratch. I was thinking for each ad that is published to create an html file. If I delete an ad from the database the html still remains. There is a way to bind the data from the mysql with the html to delete together (mysql info) + (html)?

Comment: You could obviously have a 'html_path' field, and include deleting the file in your `deleteAdvert` method. You could generate the html on the fly, removing the static html fields entirely. Any number of things. SO requires specific questions with repeatable code based problems, so this question is likely to be closed

Comment: If you end up with thousands of ads you don't want thousands of HTML files. A better way would be to use a template (or set of templates). They would be snippets of pre-built HTML and PHP, and you would use PHP to fetch the contents of a specific ad from the database, and then fill in the details in the relevant (pre-defined) places in the template. Just like this site does - notice how all the pages are basically the same layout, except the content of each part changes depending which question you're viewing? And how the URL contains the question ID? That's the kind of design you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a path to your html file in the database table as well. 
When you delete an entry with an ad, you also trigger the file deletion.

Do not forget: when you edit the ad you also need to update the corresponding html file.

Another approach would be to store the html directly in the table and use different caching solution to serve the content quickly.